# variable doesnt have a type name

Tags: arduino-uno, variables

Why can't i assign the value to a variable  outside the function?

```
void setup(){}
int a;
a=12;   //  WHY IS THIS GIVING ME ERROR
void loop(){
}
```

Why the line `a=12` gives me an error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a=12;   //  WHY IS THIS GIVING ME ERROR

Because you can't do assignments like that outside of a function.

You can, though, create *and* assign the variable at the same time:

```
int a = 12;
```

That is a declaration of the variable, whereas

```
a = 12;
```

is a procedural statement. Procedural statements cannot be executed in the global scope. They can only be executed inside a function during the execution of the program (the global scope never gets executed).

Comment: But why cannt we do that ?

Comment: Because that is the syntax of C. "Ye canne change the laws of physics, cap'n"

Comment: Actually, the global scope is used for declaration and initialization. Execution is not needed. In C it is a rule that the first function that is executed is main. And the function main should call all other functions that will be called. Note that this function is 'hidden' (auto generated) by the toolchain. Other languages (like Python) can execute code within the global scope, but for C this has not been designed.

Comment: Is it just the syntax? or is there anything else behind that?

Comment: It's just the syntax. It's done that way so that the compiler can easily tell the difference between a piece of code that should be executed (a = 12) and a variable initialization (int a = 12). In the latter the "12" is stored elsewhere (in flash), and during the startup of your code that value (and other global variables) are copied into memory in the right places.